# Why use parens instead of square brackets in ''if !(ssh ...) then''?

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to understand the use of brackets in this line:

```
if !(ssh -q $user@$server "[ -d /some/directory ]")then
```

Usually the condition comes between [], what exactly is the use of () here?

Comment: `[ ]` is not part of `if` syntax; instead, `[` is an alternate name for the command named `test`; when called under that name, it expects its last argument to be `]`. If you don't want to run `test`, then you shouldn't use `[`.

Comment: ...as for the use of `( )`, it has no use -- the person writing that code was mistaken to use it; it makes the code slower, and adds no value. If they wanted to make it clear that the `!` applies to the entirety of the `ssh` call without side effects on how the code executes, they should have written `if ! { ssh -q "$user@$server" 'test -d /some/directory'; }; then`

Comment: Why do you need to prefix your condition with `ssh`? Why can't you just use `( -q $user@$server "..." )`? Obviously it's because these are not a condition as much as flags and parameters that you pass to `/usr/bin/ssh` so it can do its thing. Why do you need to put a condition like `-d mydir` between `[`? Still because these are not conditions as much as flags and parameters that you pass to `/usr/bin/[` so it can do its thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small "debatable" (See comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48427347/8344060)) typo in your line. A space in front of your first bracket. In a shell script, the space is not needed. However, depending on some options from your shell, it might be needed to add a space when typing this line directly on the command-line. A rewrite with space would be :

```
if ! (ssh -q $user@$server "[ -d /some/directory ]"); then ... ; fi
```

There are several parts in this line

- `[ -d /some/directory ]` : this is a call to the so called `test` command which can also be written as `[ ... ]`. `test -d /some/directory` and `[ -d /some/directory ]` are identical commands. It will check if the directory `/some/directory` exists or is accessible. (see `man test` for more information)
- `ssh -q $user@$server cmd`: this will execute the command `cmd` as `$user` on `$server`. However it will do this quietly (`-q`) by not throwing any error output. So essentially, with `cmd` replaced by the above test, we check if that directory exists or is accessible for `$user` on `$server`.

  > **`man ssh ::`** `-q` :      Quiet mode.  Causes most warning and diagnostic messages to be suppressed
- The full command is now enclosed between brackets. The brackets is a grouping which allows to execute several commands in unity. I.e. `( cmd1; cmd2 )` will be executed as one unit. Nonetheless, these brackets will do this in a separate instance. It will fork a sub-shell to do the execution. In this case only a single command is being executed in the sub-shell. It's unnecessary overhead. *As you see, even though the syntax **looks** cleaner, it has an effect.*

  > **`man bash ::`** `(list)` `list` is executed in a subshell environment.  Variable assignments and builtin commands that affect the shell's environment do not remain in effect after the  command  completes. The return status is the exit status of `list`.
- `! cmd` : this negates the exit status of `cmd`. If the command successfully executed (exit status=0) it will assume to be false. Or vice versa.
- The `if` statement is written as `if list; then thenlist; fi`. The `if` statement is executed if the exit-status of `list` is zero. In this case `list` is `! (ssh -q $user@$server "[ -d /some/directory ]")`, while a more common example of `list` is `[ -e foo ]` which is the `test` command.

Similar ways of writing the if-condition are now :

```
if ! ssh -q $user@$server "[ -d /some/directory ]"; then ...; fi
```

or you can just move the `!` in the `test`, leading to :

```
if ssh -q $user@$server "[ ! -d /some/directory ]"; then ...; fi
```

Finally, if you want to keep the *grouping* for looks without the sub-shell, you can use `{ ... }`, i.e.

```
if ! { ssh -q $user@$server "[ -d /some/directory ]"; }; then ...; fi
```

> **`man bash ::`**  `{ list; }`
>             `list`  is  simply  executed  in the current shell environment.  list must be terminated with a newline or semicolon. 
>   This is known as a group command.  The return status is the exit
>   status of `list`.

Comment: Excellent answer. Keep it up! I hope we'll see more answers from you on shell questions.

Comment: @kvantour Thank you so much for this answer! I'm new to shell scripting and need to rework some existing scripts. This answer is very helpful..

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between `!` and `(...)`. One correct way to write this using `bash` shell:

```
if ! (ssh -q $user@$server "[ -d \"/some/directory\" ]"); then 
   echo "do something"; 
else 
   echo "do something else"; 
fi
```

This checks whether a directory `/some/directory` exists on a remote `server` using `ssh`.

`man test` to know about options, such as `-d`.

> ```
>  -d FILE
>         FILE exists and is a directory
> ```

`!` represents a logical (boolean) NOT or negation to the output of `()`.

`-q` option in `ssh` is for quiet mode.

For information on the single parentheses `()` in bash see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html

Note, single parentheses are used to group command lines in a subshell. As OP suggested, `()` is not strictly needed/recommended here and the same `if` condition can be written without it,

```
if ! ssh -q $user@$server "[ -d \"/some/directory\" ]"; then
.....
```

Comment: The subshell is completely useless here. Why are you advising the user to add a space (which *isn't* actually syntactically necessary; you can test yourself that `!(false) && echo "this runs"` emits `this runs` on output), when they could just take it out and run `while ! ssh ...` without the inefficiency of an extra `fork()`? -- Notably, the very documentation you link describes `( )` as *caus[ing] a subshell environment to be created*.

Comment: Your comment is appropriate for experts in shell. For someone to understand the bits of what they have written, explaining command grouping in a subshell is not doing any injustice. I guess 'no good deed goes unpunished with that downvote'. Added a note.

Comment: Better to teach it right the first time, rather than to oversimplify, teach someone something that's *wrong*, and require them to re-learn it later. That said, I do think the note repairs this adequately.

Comment: ...actually, rereading, the outright inaccuracy I downvoted for (*"You need a space between `!` and `(...)`"*) is still there. It's certainly *good style* to have that space, but it's not mandatory for correct parsing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I tested your example `!(false) && echo "this runs"` and it seems not to work in `sh`, `bash` and `zsh`. I do need the space for this.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/d1hxte, with output shown from the online interpreter as `this runs`. I'm curious as to how you got a contrary test result.

Comment: (I also get `this runs` from `dash -c '!(false) && echo "this runs"'` -- it's only zsh that behaves differently, which is no surprise as it doesn't claim to be a POSIX-compliant shell).

Comment: Even zsh runs it correctly when invoked in POSIX mode; run the following in bash to invoke zsh under the name `sh`: `(exec -a sh zsh -c '!(false) && echo "this runs"')`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, that works because your are using `bash -c`, have you tried on your shell prompt ?

Comment: @iamauser, yes; it works on every prompt but zsh, and zsh -- as I said -- is intentionally non-POSIX-compliant except when started under the name `sh`.

Comment: hmm, that's strange. I am using `bash` as my shell, and I get `-bash: !: event not found` for `!(false) && echo "this runs"`

Comment: @iamauser, ...actually, waitaminute -- it can be made to fail in bash, **if** the non-default `extglob` option is active. I don't suppose you might have that enabled in your dotfiles?

Comment: Ahh. I keep history expansion off (evil so-called "feature" that it is), so now that makes sense. (Not a fan of having code run differently between interactive and scripted use).

Comment: No, I am using the default `extglob`. Well, this proves my point of, only for experts :-)

Comment: Heh. I still wouldn't say that the OP *needs* to make a change when it's only pertinent to shells with extglobs or history expansion enabled (vs. saying that their code, say, *will be more reliable* if they make that change), but there's definitely a much stronger argument for it than I realized up-front. For the better that the downvote was retracted a good while ago, then.